# wmuSlider script works on local server, but not remote server

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, slider

I'm trying to get a jquery slider called wmu slider to work. I've downloaded the files and demo from https://github.com/pastawoua/wmuSlider and when I open up the demo.html locally everything works as it should, but when I upload it to my site nothing loads, here is the url http://www.klossal.com/wmuSlider/demo/demo.html

I've looked over everything multiple times, urls are all correct, I've been trying to fix this for hours now with no luck, any help would be really appreciated.

sorry if links didn't work for you, here is the code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- BEGIN html -->
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->

<!-- BEGIN head-->
<head>

<!-- Meta Tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-   
scale=1.0">

<!-- Title -->
<title>wmuSlider Demo</title>

<!-- Stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="modernizr.custom.min.js"></script>    
<script src="http://www.klossal.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery.wmuSlider.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery.wmuGallery.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.example1').wmuSlider(); 

    $('.example2').wmuSlider({
        touch: true,
        animation: 'slide'
    });   

    $('.example3').wmuSlider({
        touch: Modernizr.touch,
        animation: 'slide',
        items: 2
    });

    $('.example4').wmuGallery();
</script>
<!-- END head -->
</head>

<!-- BEGIN body -->
<body>

<!-- BEGIN .wmuSlider -->
<div class="wmuSlider example1">

    <div class="wmuSliderWrapper">
        <article>
            <img src="http://www.klossal.com/media/boundarywaters/boundry-1.jpg" />
        </article>

        <article>
            <img src="http://www.klossal.com/media/boundarywaters/boundry-2.jpg" />
        </article>

        <article>
            <img src="http://www.klossal.com/media/boundarywaters/boundry-3.jpg" />
        </article>

        <article>
            <img src="http://www.klossal.com/media/boundarywaters/boundry-4.jpg" />
        </article>

        <article>
            <img src="http://www.klossal.com/media/boundarywaters/boundry-5.jpg" />
        </article>

        <article>
            <img src="http://www.klossal.com/media/boundarywaters/boundry-6.jpg" />
        </article>
    </div>

<!-- END .wmuSlider -->
</div>

<!-- BEGIN .wmuSlider -->
<div class="wmuSlider example2">

    <div class="wmuSliderWrapper">
        <article>
            <img src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6052/6279000273_218313c876.jpg" />
        </article>

        <article>
            <img src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6104/6271856202_1e3ccb3deb.jpg" />
        </article>

        <article>
            <img src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6053/6268322528_818ab33f7f.jpg" />
        </article>

        <article>
            <img src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6232/6239597762_15491d4c97.jpg" />
        </article>

        <article>
            <img src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6057/6224753006_9fb962d890.jpg" />
        </article>

        <article>
            <img src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6036/6213397745_1d8f223e93.jpg" />
        </article>            
    </div>

<!-- END .wmuSlider -->
</div>

<!-- BEGIN .wmuSlider -->
<div class="wmuSlider example3">

    <div class="wmuSliderWrapper">
        <article>
            <img src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6052/6279000273_218313c876.jpg" />
        </article>

        <article>
            <img src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6104/6271856202_1e3ccb3deb.jpg" />
        </article>

        <article>
            <img src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6053/6268322528_818ab33f7f.jpg" />
        </article>

        <article>
            <img src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6232/6239597762_15491d4c97.jpg" />
        </article>

        <article>
            <img src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6057/6224753006_9fb962d890.jpg" />
        </article>

        <article>
            <img src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6036/6213397745_1d8f223e93.jpg" />
        </article>
    </div>

<!-- END .wmuSlider -->
</div>

<!-- BEGIN .wmuGallery -->
<div class="wmuGallery example4">

    <div class="wmuSlider">        
        <div class="wmuSliderWrapper">
            <article>
                <img width="75" height="75" 
src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6052/6279000273_218313c876_s.jpg" data-src-
full="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6052/6279000273_218313c876.jpg" />
            </article>

            <article>
                <img width="75" height="75" 
src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6104/6271856202_1e3ccb3deb_s.jpg" data-src-
full="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6104/6271856202_1e3ccb3deb.jpg" />
            </article>

            <article>
                <img width="75" height="75" 
src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6053/6268322528_818ab33f7f_s.jpg" data-src-
full="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6053/6268322528_818ab33f7f.jpg" />
            </article>

            <article>
                <img width="75" height="75" 
src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6232/6239597762_15491d4c97_s.jpg" data-src-
full="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6232/6239597762_15491d4c97.jpg" />
            </article>

            <article>
                <img width="75" height="75"    
src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6057/6224753006_9fb962d890_s.jpg" data-src-
full="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6057/6224753006_9fb962d890.jpg" />
            </article>

            <article>
                <img width="75" height="75" 
src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6036/6213397745_1d8f223e93_s.jpg" data-src-
full="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6036/6213397745_1d8f223e93.jpg" />
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>  

<!-- END .wmuGallery -->
</div>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="modernizr.custom.min.js"></script>    
<script src="http://www.klossal.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery.wmuSlider.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery.wmuGallery.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.example1').wmuSlider(); 

    $('.example2').wmuSlider({
        touch: true,
        animation: 'slide'
    });   

    $('.example3').wmuSlider({
        touch: Modernizr.touch,
        animation: 'slide',
        items: 2
    });

    $('.example4').wmuGallery();
</script>

<!-- END body -->
</body>
<!-- END html -->
</html>
```

There are muliple JS files, so I will link to the github of them:

https://github.com/pastawoua/wmuSlider/blob/master/jquery.wmuGallery.js

https://github.com/pastawoua/wmuSlider/blob/master/jquery.wmuslider.js

https://github.com/pastawoua/wmuSlider/blob/master/demo/modernizr.custom.min.js

here is the CSS:

https://github.com/pastawoua/wmuSlider/blob/master/demo/css/demo.css

Comment: in firefox console (Ctrl+Shift+K). You can see an error `registrar_frameset is not defined`

Comment: The link doesn't work for me.

Comment: post your code. the links either way seem down and are not useful for future references

Comment: What @newtostackoverflow said: the registrar.js couldn't be loaded from http://cdn.dsultra.com/js/registrar.js

Comment: hmm, I have no idea where or what that is, do you know how I fix that?

Comment: also updated the post for code

Comment: @loriensleafs Put your javascript inside of `$(document).ready` handler.

Comment: like this:      <script>$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.example1').wmuSlider(); 
         
        $('.example2').wmuSlider({
            touch: true,
            animation: 'slide'
        });   
        
        $('.example3').wmuSlider({
            touch: Modernizr.touch,
            animation: 'slide',
            items: 2
        });
        
        $('.example4').wmuGallery();}
    </script>

Comment: I have no idea why the source code for that page shows up the way it does when you go to my url and check the source, when I go to edit it on my server it shows up as the html code I've posted here, I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: @Engineer Add that as an answer and I'll +1 it :P

Comment: yikes, this was my site demo url, my mistake  http://www.klossal.com/js/wmuSlider/demo/demo.html

Answer (score 4):

In case this hasn't been resolved yet (or for future searchers), check each file downloaded from github.  Looks like every file, including the `sprites.png` file, is a copy of the `demo.html` file when you right click and **Save Link As**.

Look at the demo files instead and copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

capslock matters! 
change  `<script src="../jquery.wmuSlider.js"></script>`  **to**

```
<script src="../jquery.wmuslider.js"></script>
```

:)